# Unable to Publish JMS message on Soace Topic

Tags: jms, solace

We are unable to publish JMS message on Solace topic.We are ale to create Solace topic on Solace client UI.

But unable to send message on it.
we are getting below error message.

****WARN | Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'topic1' - trying to recover. 
  Cause: Error creating consumer - operation not supported on router (Capability Mismatch: Router does not support temp endpoints or session not yet connected.)****

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the application is attempting to create a MessageConsumer for a temporary endpoint, but the client does not have the right capabilities.

To resolve this, you will need to enable the "Allow Guaranteed Endpoint Create" capability in the client-profile that this client is using. You can enable this with SolAdmin, or with the Solace CLI.